# Setup TLS Certs for Prometheus adapter in Local k3d

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, ssl

I am trying to setup HorizontalPodAutoscaler in K8s, for which I am setting up a custom metric to be used by HPA. I am using k3d locally to test the autoscaling feature.

For this custom metric , I plan to modify one of the kube-state-metrics metric , and expose that metric via custom metrics server i.e prometheus adapter .

As of now ->

1 - **kube-state-metrics** - works fine - generates the metric

2 - **prometheus** - scrapes the metric successfully - the metric is showing up on the local promethues UI.

3 - **prometheus-adapter** - is able to fetch this metric successfully from prometheus.

```
I1019 06:27:53.248057       1 api.go:93] Response Body: {"status":"success","data":[{"__name__":"kube_node_status_condition","condition":"Ready","instance":"kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080","job":"kube-state-metrics","node":"k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0","status":"true"},{"__name__":"kube_node_status_condition","condition":"Ready","instance":"kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080","job":"kube-state-metrics","node":"k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1","status":"true"},{"__name__":"kube_node_status_condition","condition":"Ready","instance":"kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080","job":"kube-state-metrics","node":"k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0","status":"true"}]}
I1019 06:27:53.248155       1 provider.go:269] Set available metric list from Prometheus to: [[{kube_node_status_condition {condition="Ready", instance="kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", node="k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0", status="true"}} {kube_node_status_condition {condition="Ready", instance="kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", node="k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1", status="true"}} {kube_node_status_condition {condition="Ready", instance="kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", node="k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0", status="true"}}]]
```

Following is my prometheus-adapter deployment yaml snippet ->

```
      - name: prometheus-adapter-metrics-apiserver
        image: quay.io/coreos/k8s-prometheus-adapter-amd64:v0.4.1
        args:
        - /adapter
        - --secure-port=6443
        - --tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.crt
        - --tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.key
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --prometheus-url=http://prometheus-svc.kube-system.svc:9090
        - --metrics-relist-interval=30s
        - --v=10
        - --config=/etc/adapter/config.yaml
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6443
```

where

```
- --tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.crt
- --tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.key
```

I've generated in the following way ->

```
$openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \ -keyout serving.key -out serving.crt \ -subj "/CN=prometheus-adapter-svc.kube-system.svc"

$kubectl -n kube-system create secret generic cm-adapter-serving-certs \ --from-file=serving.crt=./serving.crt \ --from-file=serving.key=./serving.key \ -n kube-system \ --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl -n kube-system apply -f -
```

> Issue -> prometheus-adapter logs report multiple bad certificate tls
> handshake errors.

```
http: TLS handshake error from 10.42.2.0:36858: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I1019 06:28:25.106866       1 logs.go:49] http: TLS handshake error from 10.42.2.0:36872: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I wanted to understand what all certificates are required to setup for the prometheus-adapter. As I understand from searching a lot, currently some ca signed certificate is missing hence the communication with k8s api-server is failing.

We can set in prometheus-adapter with arg -> `- --client-ca-file=` , but unsure which certificate is this exactly and if this is the correct arg to use ...

Thanks.

Update -> My resource in cluster -> pods and svcs in kube-system ->

```
$kks get po -o wide

NAME                                                   READY   STATUS      RESTARTS       AGE     IP           NODE                            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
helm-install-traefik-fs8v9                             0/1     Completed   0              3d14h   <none>       k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1    <none>           <none>
helm-install-traefik-crd-dlfv9                         0/1     Completed   0              3d14h   <none>       k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0    <none>           <none>
svclb-traefik-3222557f-zr8sr                           2/2     Running     6 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.0.26   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0    <none>           <none>
svclb-traefik-3222557f-6ltck                           2/2     Running     6 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.1.24   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1    <none>           <none>
local-path-provisioner-957fdf8bc-dk64x                 1/1     Running     4 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.0.25   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0    <none>           <none>
kube-state-metrics-59dd94cfd9-94hdp                    1/1     Running     4 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.0.24   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0    <none>           <none>
metrics-server-648b5df564-cqm7z                        1/1     Running     4 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.1.23   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1    <none>           <none>
traefik-64f55bb67d-ff92g                               1/1     Running     4 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.2.16   k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0   <none>           <none>
coredns-77ccd57875-7cdfx                               1/1     Running     3 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.1.21   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-1    <none>           <none>
kube-state-metrics-59dd94cfd9-x5x2m                    1/1     Running     6 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.2.18   k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0   <none>           <none>
svclb-traefik-3222557f-fdjbd                           2/2     Running     6 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.2.15   k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0   <none>           <none>
prometheus-deployment-59fc9f75c7-t9jj9                 1/1     Running     3 (129m ago)   3d14h   10.42.2.17   k3d-two-node-cluster-server-0   <none>           <none>
prometheus-adapter-metrics-apiserver-b969cc999-k52xx   1/1     Running     0              9m14s   10.42.0.28   k3d-two-node-cluster-agent-0    <none>           <none>


$kks get svc -o wide

NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                        PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
kube-dns                 ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>                             53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       3d14h   k8s-app=kube-dns
metrics-server           ClusterIP      10.43.170.193   <none>                             443/TCP                      3d14h   k8s-app=metrics-server
kube-state-metrics       ClusterIP      None            <none>                             8080/TCP,8081/TCP            3d14h   app=kube-state-metrics
prometheus-svc           ClusterIP      10.43.98.232    <none>                             9090/TCP                     3d14h   app=prometheus-svc
prometheus-adapter-svc   ClusterIP      10.43.128.15    <none>                             443/TCP                      3d4h    app=prometheus-adapter-metrics-apiserver
traefik                  LoadBalancer   10.43.141.177   172.19.0.2,172.19.0.3,172.19.0.4   80:32437/TCP,443:31229/TCP   3d14h   app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik-kube-system,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
```

I also see in prometheus-adapter logs ->

```
I1019 08:34:47.015661       1 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: adapter/v0.0.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/$Format" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InpLNWZvZjBPVkVlUklDUFBBdUdkUzdVZ2JPcWF4VFhvZUg3TW9yRlBQTHcifQ.eyJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9rdWJlcm5ldGVzLmRlZmF1bHQuc3ZjLmNsdXN0ZXIubG9jYWwiLCJrM3MiXSwiZXhwIjoxNzI5MjQwNDg0LCJpYXQiOjE2OTc3MDQ0ODQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8va3ViZXJuZXRlcy5kZWZhdWx0LnN2Yy5jbHVzdGVyLmxvY2FsIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pbyI6eyJuYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJrdWJlLXN5c3RlbSIsInBvZCI6eyJuYW1lIjoicHJvbWV0aGV1cy1hZGFwdGVyLW1ldHJpY3MtYXBpc2VydmVyLWI5NjljYzk5OS1jbncycSIsInVpZCI6IjMyNTAwNGE2LTgwMDctNDUzZC05Y2JhLTYyMzA0YmFhOWZjMyJ9LCJzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudCI6eyJuYW1lIjoicHJvbWV0aGV1cy1hZGFwdGVyIiwidWlkIjoiOWZhNTkwNjktOTMzYS00ODkzLWEwYjItZDZkNzQ1MThiZDU5In0sIndhcm5hZnRlciI6MTY5NzcwODA5MX0sIm5iZiI6MTY5NzcwNDQ4NCwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Omt1YmUtc3lzdGVtOnByb21ldGhldXMtYWRhcHRlciJ9.ul8I2xSnEDvNIfzca8cnec2pzhgfr0qB5ueIMdoq76Gilc_7mgEgdFuFUPmnPjqXN2fwg2PpRxFddTsfbfPjtnH7_i7i1A955fE7KT2eO3x8_ISYz6ceKxoRGiglqwvY7X6Sg7JzkDniKzhH9mA700XgQ6vOxmrM-DvuQMHCvXoLRfKNh0p21-y3se0moS8YgEzUzopl9UfLIki3STM3-0AtXy9QPDk_J8OtldrEY6zIht26oW26EQjtNpG8jqk0TNM6v8aHpXBcFqmRf-9p0-m4YYVwTXt3C3yOqGndns8Pfc1A3rP48B4cXTWKRLUiOwOwtr_8BLaGDD_3Fru0MA" 'https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication'
I1019 08:34:47.023667       1 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication 200 OK in 6 milliseconds
I1019 08:34:47.023770       1 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1019 08:34:47.023830       1 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I1019 08:34:47.023907       1 round_trippers.go:414]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: fe85b78e-5edc-4399-96ed-cdef06d6958d
I1019 08:34:47.023938       1 round_trippers.go:414]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: d63b6c6c-1a2f-4ee2-bd3d-541aca483d77
I1019 08:34:47.023974       1 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 2071
I1019 08:34:47.024002       1 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Thu, 19 Oct 2023 08:34:47 GMT
I1019 08:34:47.024027       1 round_trippers.go:414]     Audit-Id: 71225c64-0c5d-4b04-9b24-1ff602446adc
I1019 08:34:47.024052       1 round_trippers.go:414]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I1019 08:34:47.024142       1 request.go:897] Response Body: {"kind":"ConfigMap","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"extension-apiserver-authentication","namespace":"kube-system","uid":"2a0ec951-09af-4594-9831-08730ea6e8fa","resourceVersion":"35","creationTimestamp":"2023-10-15T17:51:18Z","managedFields":[{"manager":"k3s","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2023-10-15T17:51:18Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:data":{".":{},"f:client-ca-file":{},"f:requestheader-allowed-names":{},"f:requestheader-client-ca-file":{},"f:requestheader-extra-headers-prefix":{},"f:requestheader-group-headers":{},"f:requestheader-username-headers":{}}}}]},"data":{"client-ca-file":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBdzCCAR2gAwIBAgIBADAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAjMSEwHwYDVQQDDBhrM3MtY2xp\nZW50LWNhQDE2OTczOTIyNzQwHhcNMjMxMDE1MTc1MTE0WhcNMzMxMDEyMTc1MTE0\nWjAjMSEwHwYDVQQDDBhrM3MtY2xpZW50LWNhQDE2OTczOTIyNzQwWTATBgcqhkjO\nPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAASsUtUTXd7t6MUNk3WtUyKKz5HrGTZttPc1/5hgLEWs\nhuIPCnY3ae7XnLYXXKNTuUONTuhjWcAT3PgITwb8orU4o0IwQDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\nBAMCAqQwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUTm+ARhpwNc9mDkT1YSPl\nSu+rU7MwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAPbtuNUwNW13KAcuo0SDcouXjyfXb1cz\nX4mWtj//MO0pAiAmqJH37r1/nWy3wR6/ht3feE1JLa+Yv2gfOXMgBZjpvg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","requestheader-allowed-names":"[\"system:auth-proxy\"]","requestheader-client-ca-file":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nxrxz5hA9TP4ZVu4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","requestheader-extra-headers-prefix":"[\"X-Remote-Extra-\"]","requestheader-group-headers":"[\"X-Remote-Group\"]","requestheader-username-headers":"[\"X-Remote-User\"]"}}
```